# How to call WCF URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-rest

I have created a simple test service as below. I want to give the URL to my client as defined in URI Template.
I have hosted the service in IIS.
How can I create the url for the below service??????

wsdl document is shown as per expected.
I want the url to match URITemplate.

Please suggest

**IService1.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "?value={value}")]
    string GetData(string value);


    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

**Service1.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    #region IService1 Members

    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return "Hello " + value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**WEB.Config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Check.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Check.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehavior"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Check" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restfulBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can your make your UriTemplate be UriTemplate = "/GetData?value={value}")?

Comment: I tried with this also /GetData?value={value} still no luck

Comment: what is the url? Did you call this from browser location bar?

Answer (score 1):

I just used your code it's working fine for me using below URL:

```
http://[HostAddress]/service1.svc/?value=1
```

I am getting this in Response:

```
{
    GetDataResult: "Hello 1"
}
```

Check if it works for you.